# Javascript looping inside a function

Tags: javascript

```
<script src="value.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function value(v) {
        if (value1 === 1 && value2 === 10) {
            return table();
        } else {
            alert("Your values are not correct!");
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have a form that when the user clicks a button the value function runs and a table is shown. In this function I have an if statement that only shows the table when both value1 and value2 are correct. If not then the alert shows instead.

What I would like to do is have the alert keep showing each time the button is clicked until the values are correct. I have tried different combos of loops and etc. but I can't figure out how to get the alert to keep showing until both values are correct. I have been searching the net for two days trying to get it to loop back to the alert. Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Show us how the code of the button and how you are calling `value`. Usually the handler will be called every time the button is clicked - without any loop - so that's where something goes wrong.

Comment: you don't show where `value1` and `value2` come from

Comment: show me your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get value1 and value2 are they globally scoped variables and what is the argument v that you never use.  At any rate the simplest thing would be to pass value1 and value2 as arguments to your function.

```
function value(value1, value2)
{
    if (value1 === 1 && value2 === 10){
        return table();}
    else {alert("Your values are not correct!")};
}
```

and on your button or however you call the value function

```
<button onclick="value(v1, v2)" />
```

Comment: so, where would v1 and v2 come from in the onclick attribute?

Comment: He never said how he was calling the method, so I just gave a quick example that was easy to type from my phone, I just think it's funny how ppl are quick to down vote with providing a solution or trying to help

Comment: The values come from a separate js file. The function is called with <onclick="return value(this.form)"/>

Comment: This answer is not bad .. The question can not be answered until the author does not provide the code where the function are called.